# Ask about correct parsing JSON in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x

I have part of code in Python which works well. It's below.

```
def get_weather_from_response(json): 
  return WeatherInfo(json['main']['temp'], json['weather'][0]['description'])
```

example JSON for this code v2.5:

```json
{
    "coord": {
        "lon": -94.5783,
        "lat": 39.0997
    },
    "weather": [
        {
            "id": 800,
            "main": "Clear",
            "description": "clear sky",
            "icon": "01d"
        }
    ],
    "base": "stations",
    "main": {
        "temp": 298.73,
        "feels_like": 298.36,
        "temp_min": 297.86,
        "temp_max": 300.19,
        "pressure": 1013,
        "humidity": 39
    },
    "visibility": 10000,
    "wind": {
        "speed": 1.79,
        "deg": 117,
        "gust": 5.81
    },
    "clouds": {
        "all": 0
    },
    "dt": 1686330626,
    "sys": {
        "type": 2,
        "id": 47709,
        "country": "US",
        "sunrise": 1686307936,
        "sunset": 1686361383
    },
    "timezone": -18000,
    "id": 4393217,
    "name": "Kansas City",
    "cod": 200
}
```

But I'd like to change version of API from 2.5 to 3.0 and I got more deeply structure JSON in answer API-call. Answer from v3.0

```json
{
    "lat": 51.4875,
    "lon": -0.1687,
    "timezone": "Europe/London",
    "timezone_offset": 3600,
    "current": {
        "dt": 1686330553,
        "sunrise": 1686282287,
        "sunset": 1686341709,
        "temp": 297.22,
        "feels_like": 297.07,
        "pressure": 1012,
        "humidity": 53,
        "dew_point": 287.05,
        "uvi": 1.5,
        "clouds": 0,
        "visibility": 10000,
        "wind_speed": 6.69,
        "wind_deg": 80,
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

How can I change this row?

```py
def get_weather_from_response(json):
  return WeatherInfo(json['main']['temp'], json['weather'][0]['description'])
```

I tried like this, but it was unsuccessful

```py
def get_weather_from_response(json):
  return WeatherInfo(json['main']['temp'], json[0]['weather'][0]['description'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
data = {
    "lat": 51.4875,
    "lon": -0.1687,
    "timezone": "Europe/London",
    "timezone_offset": 3600,
    "current": {
        "dt": 1686330553,
        "sunrise": 1686282287,
        "sunset": 1686341709,
        "temp": 297.22,
        "feels_like": 297.07,
        "pressure": 1012,
        "humidity": 53,
        "dew_point": 287.05,
        "uvi": 1.5,
        "clouds": 0,
        "visibility": 10000,
        "wind_speed": 6.69,
        "wind_deg": 80,
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 800,
                "main": "Clear",
                "description": "clear sky",
                "icon": "01d"
            }
        ]
    }
}

def get_weather_from_response(data):
    return data['current']['temp'], data['current']['weather'][0]['description']


print(get_weather_from_response(data))
```

Prints:

```
(297.22, 'clear sky')
```